# Question about memory management/free lists using Red-Black trees and Doubly linked list to achieve constant time memory coalescence

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, time-complexity

Preface: I'm trying to understand data structures and algorithms as they pertain to memory allocation strategies. In this context, there is a large fixed-size pool of memory, from which blocks will be allocated to a user/deallocated from a user similar to calling `malloc()` or `free()`.

Reading through this article:

https://www.gingerbill.org/article/2021/11/30/memory-allocation-strategies-005/

He mentions near the end about using a sorted doubly linked list to achieve coalescence operations in O(1) time. I'm struggling to imagine how a linked list is applied to achieve a constant time complexity.

My first thought was that the list would be sorted by the addresses of each node pointer so that a simple calculation of `(Node + Node->size == Node->next)` would tell you if two memory blocks can be merged, but insertion would be an O(N) operation because you need to find the appropriate place to insert a new node when it becomes free. Also, this usage of a doubly linked list isn't terribly different than the first half of that article, in using a singly linked list to perform all of the allocation/freeing of blocks of a pool of memory.

Can someone clarify the purpose of the doubly-linked-list working in tandem with a red-black-tree to achieve O(log(n)) insertion and removal (deallocation and allocation, respectively), and O(1) coalescence?

Comment: I haven't read the article, but my first thought is you'd have the list sorted by block size so you could do a binary search (or similar) to find the first "big enough" block. It's probably still not O(1) though.

Comment: @John3136 Sorry my post wasn't clear. The red black tree is used to perform best-fit-search for a block of memory. Its implied in the article that the doubly-linked-list is used at some point during freeing a block because of coalescence, but I don't understand it past that.

Comment: I still haven't read the article, but that makes a bit more sense. If you are sorted on address then when you do a "free" you can look at the previous and next blocks of the block you just freed and see if you can coalesce (i.e. make one big block out of 2 smaller ones), so that would be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

The doubly-linked list contains all blocks (both free and allocated), sorted by the start address, so when a block becomes free, it's a `O(1)` operation to check whether either (or both) of its left and right neighbors are also free. If so, it's a `O(logN)` operation to merge with them: merging would remove an entry (or two) from the list (`O(1)`) and increase the size of the block being merged into (updating it in the tree - `O(logN)`), so the list needs to be somehow cross-linked with the tree to find that block's node. If not, it's a `O(logN)` operation to insert this new free block into the tree.

Allocating would find a best-fit free block node in the tree (`O(logN)`), reduce its size (updating, or removing it from the tree if the sizes match - both `O(logN)`), and split the "free" entry in the list into "allocated" and "free" entries of smaller size (`O(1)`), so the tree also needs to be cross-linked with the list to find that entry.

Depending on your memory layout, you might also need additional hashmap to be able to lookup in `O(1)` the allocated list entry by pointer (when doing `free()`), and also be able to tell in `O(1)` whether a block in the list is free or allocated.

Or you can have everything laid out flat in memory, as in [this Boost doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/interprocess/memory_algorithms.html) diagram for `rbtree_best_fit`.

So, both `malloc()` and `free()` would necessarily modify the tree and so unavoidably are `O(logN)` worst-case. However, coalescing specifically is `O(1)` thanks to the doubly-linked list.